# Best practice for initializing an injected dependency?

Tags: php, laravel, dependency-injection

I have an EmailProvider I'm injecting through my constructor.  At runtime, it needs to be initialized with the host, port, etc.  These settings can change per varying user input.  What's the best practice way to initialize an injected dependency?

Should I instead be injecting an Abstract Interface with a create method?  And this create method takes the initialization params?

```
class DataProvider {

  private $emailProvider;

  public function __construct(EmailProvider $emailProvider) {
    $this->emailProvider = $emailProvider;
  }

  public function getEmails($args) {
    $this->emailProvider->initialize($args['host'], $args['port']);  // bad?
    return $this->emailProvider->getAll();
  }

}
```

Comment: Anything that varies on user input shouldn't be handled during dependency injection. In your example code, you've hardcoded `imap.gmail.com` and `993`, but I assume these are coming from somewhere else?

Comment: right, i've updated the post - i'd have to do something more like what i changed it to

Comment: The updated version is fine -- it's not trying to initialize() in the constructor. The other way was insanity.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but couldn't you just also inject a mail settings object along with EmailProvider?

Comment: Inject a mail settings object into the EmailProvider?  Or inject it into the DataProvider?  Either way I'd have to change the settings when I request getEmails

Answer (score 0):

To make some initialisation you can bind your provider to the container using `singleton()` call with closure:

```
App::singleton(EmailProvider::class, function() {
    return new EmailProvider(config('email.host'), config('email.port'));
});
```

This call should be located in some of the application providers (`App\Providers` namespace)